# Code for shallow water equation

Tags: matlab

I want to write a MATLAB code for Roe solver for 1D shallow water equations.

Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Your question as it is right now is too vague to be properly addressed. You can improve it by adding: the equation you want solve, the purpose of this solution, the numerical methods you already know, the numerical methods you want to use, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at Randall J LeVeque's [book](http://www.cambridge.org/nl/academic/subjects/mathematics/numerical-analysis/finite-volume-methods-hyperbolic-problems) on Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems. He provides you with the necessary equations and algorithms. You can use this to build your code.

If you need additional help, you can also have a look at [CLAWPACK](http://www.clawpack.org/book.html), his own set of codes that solve a variety of example problems which include Shallow water equations. I believe you should be able to find what you are looking for, in his examples. From there on, you just have to convert the code to MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project named FullSWOF which solves Shallow Water Equations with many solvers. Unfortunately it is written by C++.

http://www.univ-orleans.fr/mapmo/soft/FullSWOF/

You can download the project here http://4share.vn/f/2b1f131b131c1b1a/FullSWOF_1D-1.02.01_win.zip This is my copied zip file of the project.

You can also read my work here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292617263_Numerical_methods_for_Shallow_water_equations

In that report I wrote MATLAB codes for Shallow Water Equations with Rusanov, HLL and MUSCL-Hancock solvers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can contact me via my email dangtruong080593@gmail.com for further discussion. Actually to get Roe scheme I only have to adapt my codes a little bit.